# how can i use urls properly always showing import error

Tags: python, django

[image]

want to build blog application following by the tutorials but urls show some import error as cannot import name URLs

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include,url

app_name='blog'
namespace='blog'

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^blog/',include('blog.urls',)),

]
```

Comment: This is defined in `blog/urls.py`?

Comment: Can you please post the *full* traceback?

Comment: File "/home/shakil/Downloads/django_project/mysite/blog/urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import urls
ImportError: cannot import name 'urls'
(its the problem showing again and again)

Comment: You made a typo, it is `url`, not `urls`. It looks like you did not share the file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56200380/how-can-i-use-urls-properly-always-showing-import-error?noredirect=1#comment99023835_56200380) you wrote:

> ```
> File "/home/shakil/Downloads/django_project/mysite/blog/urls.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from django.conf.urls import urls
> ImportError: cannot import name 'urls'
> ```

You thus have written a line where you import `urls` from `django.conf.urls`, but that module does *not* export an identifier `urls`, it however exports `url`. You thus should import it as:

```
# /home/shakil/Downloads/django_project/mysite/blog/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
```

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include

Comment: did this as follows but I am getting the same error yet

Comment: @MahamodulShakil: well the traceback shows it different. Notice that the file is `/home/shakil/Downloads/django_project/mysite/blog/urls.py`, so perhaps you are editing the wrong file. It might also help to remove the `*.pyc` files (since these ar caches).